# Maven: Failed to deploy artifacts, Acces denied

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a Sonatype Nexus server and I want to deploy a snapshot.

This is a snippet of my settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>test-snapshots</id>
    <username>myname1</username>
    <password>mypasswd1</password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>test-releases</id>
    <username>myname2</username>
    <password>mypasswd2</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

And this a snippet of my pom.xml file:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>test-releases</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>https://nxs.company.com/content/repositories/test-releases</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>test-snapshots</id>
    <name>Snapshots</name>
    <url>https://nxs.company.com/content/repositories/test-snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Doing a `mvn deploy` (Maven 3.0.3) I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy 
(default-deploy) on project MyProject: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
Could not transfer artifact com.company.project:MyProject:jar:1.0.0-20121003.154427-1 
from/to test-snapshots (https://nxs.company.com/content/repositories/test-snapshots): 
Access denied to: https://nxs.company.com/content/repositories/test-snapshots/
com.company.project/MyProject/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/MyProject-1.0.0-20121003.154427-1.jar
-> [Help 1]
```

And in my Nexus logfile, I see that no credentials are received, so it will try it later with anonymous and this will of course fail. So why are no credentials passed to Nexus?

```
2012-10-03 17:24:14 DEBUG [1027496148-8353] - org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager - Unable to resolve session ID from SessionKey [org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.WebSessionKey@791a17dc].  Returning null to indicate a session could not be found.
2012-10-03 17:24:14 DEBUG [1027496148-8353] - org.sonatype.nexus.security.filter.authc.NexusContentAuthenticationFilter - No authorization found (header or request parameter)
2012-10-03 17:24:14 DEBUG [1027496148-8353] - org.sonatype.nexus.security.filter.authc.NexusContentAuthenticationFilter - No authorization found (header or request parameter)
2012-10-03 17:24:14 DEBUG [1027496148-8353] - org.sonatype.nexus.security.filter.authc.NexusContentAuthenticationFilter - Attempting to authenticate Subject as Anonymous request...
2012-10-04 17:24:14 DEBUG [1027496148-8353] - org.sonatype.security.ldap.realms.DefaultLdapContextFactory - Initializing LDAP context using URL [ldap://10.100.100.1:3268/DC=company,DC=com] and username [ldap@company.com] with pooling [enabled]
```

Comment: Have you verified that your user account has permissions for that specific repository? See: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-privs.html

Comment: Yes, the user has the permission. But it seems the user can not login in, because there are no credentials in the request.

Comment: What's in the Nexus "authorization and authentication events" system feed?

Comment: At first sight, everything looks correctly set up. Can you open the snapshot repository url in your web browser and access contents of the repository using credentials from `settings.xml` ? Also, you could try to execute deploy with `-X` to get debug info (maybe something will show up there).

Comment: I already used the `-X` flag, but no more information. Yes, I can access the snapshot repository url, which contains one file `arcehtype-catalog.xml` with only one single line `<archetype-catalog/>`. Login to the Nexus frontend, I see in the log files "Using authorization header from request". This is missing if I want to deploy.

Comment: what user repos do you use? the ldap line at the end may indicate some missconfiguration, maybee maven will retry with credentials when told to. is the row of user repos in nexus correct?

Comment: The LDAP connection is okay. Login to the UI works, only deployment not.

Comment: I have also same type issue.Please go to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721155/maven-releaseperform-failure

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have different username/password for each repository in Nexus? This will cause a problem with the maven http wagon because the jvm caches credentials per host and even though maven presents the alternate credentials properly, the jvm won't use them. The workaround to this is to use the webdav wagon instead since this uses the apache http client instead of the jdk urlclient.

Comment: For my Nexus repo I have one username/password combination, but I integrate also some other repositories for which I need different username / password. So it must work if I only use one username/password combination? WebDav wagon? How can I use this and what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

our nexus server has multiple accounts. in windows user_home/.m2/settings it has:

```
    <server>
        <!-- this id should match the id of the repo server in pom.xml -->
        <id>release-nexus</id>
        <username>aa</username>
        <password>AA</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <!-- this id should match the id of the repo server in pom.xml -->
        <id>snapshots-nexus</id>
        <username>aa</username>
        <password>AA</password>
    </server>
```

And in project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some.groupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>release-nexus</id>  
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>  
      <url>http://nexus.foo.net/nexus/content/repositories/aa/</url> 
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots-nexus</id>  
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>  
      <url>http://nexus.foo.net/nexus/content/repositories/aa_snapshot/</url>  
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

after running `mvn deploy`

The output is:

[image: output when mvn deploy succeed]

All `<repository>`s configured in settings are different than what we used in project pom `distributionManagement`. If I put what in settings in pom, it would result in a same error `forbidden`. I found the correct url when I logged in nexus server with the username and password `aa` and `AA`, and I found there is a `aa` and `aa_snapshort`. So I guess authorities for `PUT` operation is actually on a much more detailed level.

Answer (score 0):

you need the 'settings' element as root, 
put this in your settings.xml file:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>test-snapshots</id>
            <username>myname1</username>
            <password>mypasswd1</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>test-releases</id>
            <username>myname2</username>
            <password>mypasswd2</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```